# Renaming iteratively product of variables

Tags: manipulate

It is a rather easy problem but I don't manage to solve it.

```
Expand[(a[1] x + a[2] y + a[3] z) (b[1] x + b[2] y + b[3] z) (c[1] x +
 c[2] y + c[3] z)]
```

The problem is that is gives me product of a[i] b[j] c[k] as coefficients and I would like to have instead something like d[ijk].

Example :

```
a[1]b[3]c[2] xyz -> d[132] xyz
```

Attempt :

```
equa = Expand[(a[1] x + a[2] y + a[3] z) (b[1] x + b[2] y + 
     b[3] z) (c[1] x + c[2] y + c[3] z)]
For[i = 1, i <= 3, i++,
 For [j = 1, j <= 3, j++,
  For[k = 1, k <= 3, k++,
   equa = equa /. {a[i] b[j] c[k] -> d[i j k]}
    ]]]
```

but ijk in d[i j k] are multiplied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
exp = Expand[(a[1] x + a[2] y + a[3] z) (b[1] x + b[2] y + 
     b[3] z) (c[1] x + c[2] y + c[3] z)];

exp /. t_. a[i_] b[j_] c[k_] :> t d@FromDigits[{i, j, k}]
```

> x^3 d[111] + x^2 y d[112] + x^2 z d[113] + x^2 y d[121] + 
>    x y^2 d[122] + x y z d[123] + x^2 z d[131] + x y z d[132] + 
>    x z^2 d[133] + x^2 y d[211] + x y^2 d[212] + x y z d[213] + 
>    x y^2 d[221] + y^3 d[222] + y^2 z d[223] + x y z d[231] + 
>    y^2 z d[232] + y z^2 d[233] + x^2 z d[311] + x y z d[312] + 
>    x z^2 d[313] + x y z d[321] + y^2 z d[322] + y z^2 d[323] + 
>    x z^2 d[331] + y z^2 d[332] + z^3 d[333]